# Catch a swift_TransportException

Tags: laravel, exception, slack, laravel-7, swiftmailer

I'm receiving a lot of "Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host ..." on my slack channel. Everything seems to work fine and the mail service is doing its job. I don't want to receive this certain message on my slack. Can I use $dontreport to help prevent receiving this message? If so, can you please help me out? Is there anyway to catch the exception and exclude it from slack?
(Laravel 7)
Thank you in advance